# Why does navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() returns different coordinates even while standing at the same location?

Tags: javascript, navigator

I have created an app which is used to calculate distance. It works by saving a starting location and evaluates the distance of current position from this position using a logic which is working fine. But the problem is navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() returns me varying coordinates even while standing at the same point, this coordinates range up to a distance of even 30 meters from exact location. Can anyone suggest how can i get exact coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `enableHighAccuracy` to `true`?

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have tried both enableHighAccuracy to be true as well as false, but it did no benefit